# checkout_onepage_controller_success_action event save entry in custom table on order success in magento2

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3

i have created event and observer checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
now I want to save data in the custom table of order success when order is placed
event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="checkout_controller_success_action" 
 instance="Magneto\Hometryon\Observer\AfterPlaceOrder"  />
</event>
</config>
```

AfterPlaceOrder.php

```
<?php
namespace Magneto\Hometryon\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_order;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
) {
     $this->_order = $order;    
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

    foreach($orderids as $orderid){
        $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
    }
}

}
```

now on order success, I have to save entry in custom table

Comment: Have you build model  & Resource model class for that custom table?

Comment: yes i have built static data is inserting into it now i want to add order data

Comment: @Ashish Ramchandani, you don't give any answer to my query. Please specify your table structure? Have you create columns at database for saving    order data

Comment: yes i have created created columns

Comment: Have you done it??

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Your observer file should be like this,

Inject your model in your constructor then create factory object of that and insert data into it like below

```
<?php
namespace Magneto\Hometryon\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
class AfterPlaceOrder implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $_order;
protected $_dataFactory;
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order,
 \{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\DataFactory  $dataFactory  // this should be your model file
) {
    $this->_dataFactory = $dataFactory;
    $this->_order = $order;    
}

/**
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
 * @return void
*/
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
  $order = $this->_order->get($order_ids);           
  $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();

  $saveData = $this->_dataFactory->create();
  $model->addData([
        "column_name" => $order_id,
        "column_name" => 'Content 01',
        "column_name" => true
        ]);
    $saveData = $model->save();
    if($saveData){
        $this->messageManager->addSuccess( __('Insert Record Successfully !') );
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT :**

In similar way you can set order data into your custom table and get data like this

```
  $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
  $order = $this->_order->get($order_ids);           
  $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();   
  $customer_email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
  foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
  {
        $item->getName();
        $item->getSku();
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but thorugh this static data will save i want to save order data into my custom table

Comment: Yes you can save order to your custom table as well

Comment: but I want to save only some data like the order number, order date, items(sku), status, website

Comment: @AshishRamchandani updated the answer to get order data and set it to your custom table

Comment: can you please update the answer in observer i am not getting where to keep that code

Comment: what to write in column model fields in observer

Comment: Updated the code to set increment id and in similar way you can set remaining data.